# Deny Access from IP range on 1 file/api

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web-config

Itried using mod_rewrite to deny access to 1 file on my web server. But it didn't work.

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} =10\.0\.0\.145
RewriteRule ^/mylog/_myapi - [F]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the leading slash. In apache 2.*, it's removed before being applied to rules in htaccess files:

```
RewriteRule ^mylog/_myapi - [F]
```